# Login with Facebook and PHP, CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-3

JS:

```
$('#login').click(function(e){
    FB.login(function(response){

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            window.top.location ="/login/facebook";
        });
    },{scope: 'email',return_scopes: true});
    return false;
});
```

PHP callback:

```
public function facebook(){
    $this->load->library("session");
    require_once APPPATH.'../vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => FB_APP_ID, // Replace {app-id} with your app id
        'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    ]);

    //$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

        var_dump($accessToken);
        $response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=email,cover', $accessToken->getValue());
        $result = $response->getGraphUser();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

The site is on subdomain. On basic domain there is another site where Facebook login works fine.
But here I have a problem, because `var_dump($accessToken);` returns `NULL`,

I get and this message:

`Message: Call to a member function getValue() on null`

The app domain for this site is `subdomain.site.com`.